# Sending data from client javascript file to server javascript file (node.js or other) and getting the response back

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, server

**TL;DR:**
How can I send data from client-side javascript to server-side javascript file (node.js or whatever), receive it there (and do some stuff with it), then send it back to client-side javascript file for further usage?

**Full description of the issue**

There is an HTML page with a form, from which `myjavascript.js` collect user input and process it on client side (using FormData). Then `myjavascript.js` sends the processed input to `myphp.php` (server-side) this way:

**myjavascript.js:**

```
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "../../myphp.php",false);
ajax.send(formdata);
return ajax.responseText;
```

The data (formdata) is then received by `myphp.php`, undergoes some further processing, and then is sent back to the `myjavascript.js`:..

**myphp.php:**

```
$fieldOne = $_POST["fieldOne"];
$fieldTwo = $_POST["fieldTwo"];
...
($fieldOne, $fieldTwo etc. are processed, and the result is assigned to $results)
...
echo json_encode($results);
exit();
```

... where it is returned by **`return ajax.responseText;`** (as in `myjavascript.js` code above). And then this data is displayed on the HTML page etc.

**The question**

I used to do this way before. Now I would like to use server-side javascript (say, `myserver.js`) instead of `myphp.php`. I have the code for processing the data in `myserver.js`, I just do not understand how to receive the data from `myjavascript.js` and send the response back. Is it possible, and if yes, how the code for it should look like? Generally, I do not quite understand how the mechanism of receiving POST data in server-side javascript (and sending the response back) differs from the PHP one. Thank you for any suggestions and comments.

Comment: "the mechanism of receiving POST data in server-side javascript (and sending the response back) differs from the PHP one" — It generally doesn't aside from the names of where things are put, but the specifics depend on what libraries you are using to write your server side JS. e.g. Express is very different from Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, the web server portion is typically implemented by some other framework, and your PHP scripts are called by that framework. For example, an Apache module may call your `blah.php` script incoming web request is for `/blah.php`. This means PHP developers often think in terms of the browser calling a PHP file, but it's actually more complicated than that behind the scenes.

A typical Node.js setup, in contrast, is that the JavaScript code itself implements the web server listener. You run node with your server JS script, and that script starts the server. The built-in `http` module, for example, lets you implement an low-level HTTP listener through [`createServer`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener):

```js
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { once } = require('events');

const server = createServer(async (req, res) => {
  const chunks = [];
  req.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
  await once(req, 'end');

  const body = JSON.parse(chunks.join(''));

  // Do stuff with the body

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end('Success!');
});
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Server is listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080/');
```

So basically, stop thinking in terms of a client-side JavaScript file sending things to a server-side JavaScript file and think in terms of your browser sending an HTTP request to your HTTP server.

I'd recommend you use a framework instead like [`express`](https://expressjs.com/) or [`koa`](https://koajs.com/) to build your server since it lets you more easily configure route-specific handling for requests, and they have the ability to use pre-built "middlewares" to do the common stuff like JSON body parsing and much more.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Regarding the client-side javascript, can I still use XMLHttpRequest the same way I did for PHP, or now I have to switch to fetch method or similar?

Comment: You can use either one. The server will get an HTTP request regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **node js** and **express js** so that you can reach your goal easily.

Run the following commands after installed node js:

```
$ npm install express --save

$ npm install body-parser --save
```

**myserver.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use( bodyParser.json() )
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.fieldOne)
    console.log(req.body.fieldTwo)

    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

And then, run your server with the bellow command:

```
$ node myserver.js
```